# Cloud-init expire true issue

Tags: openstack, cloud-init

After add expire: true in the cloud-init script, I can log in via key to the server, but it says You must change your password now and login again!
I want if I set the password, the password expires after the first login and if I set a key, the system does not ask for the current password. Is there any solution?

This is my script

#cloud-config
password: {$password}
chpasswd: {literal}{expire: True}{/literal}
ssh_pwauth: True
ssh_authorized_keys:
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to cloud-init, if a user's password is expired, they cannot login over SSH, even with valid keys. There are, however, [ways to work around this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440055).